# Separate entities with common parent vs 1 entity with nullable properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working with .NET Core and Entity Framework Core and need to create an app where Employee can create 3 types of posts:

- Idea - telling about what he think could change in organization. It have props:

  - Description
  - AttachmentId
- Article Request - telling that there is need for something ex. new smartphone

  - ArticleId
  - Cost
- Question

  - CategoryId

All three have some common properties which are: Id, AddedDate, Responses (list), Notifications. And each Response has list of Comments.

I'm wondering what's the proper way to write this.

a) So 1st option - separate classes:

If I will make 3 separate classes with base class then I'll end up with 3 tables for those 3 post types and there will be the same Ids for both - I mean there will be Question with Id=1, and Idea with Id=1.

On Response class I can't reference it by `PostId`, because it doesn't actually exist I would do something like that:

```
class BaseResponse<TPost> where TPost : BasePost {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
    public TPost Post { get; set; }
}

class IdeaResponse : BaseResponse<Idea> {}
class ArticleRequestResponse : BaseResponse<ArticleRequest> {}
class QuestionResponse : BaseResponse<Question> {}
```

and in Context.cs:

```
public DbSet<Idea> Ideas { get; set; }
public DbSet<ArticleRequest> ArticleRequests { get; set; }
public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }

public DbSet<IdeaResponse> IdeaResponses { get; set; }
public DbSet<ArticleRequestResponse> ArticleRequestResponses { get; set; }
public DbSet<QuestionResponse> QuestionResponses { get; set; }
```

So also 3 classes for responses, and then similar thing for notifications and also comments

b) 2nd option: 1 class with nullable properties with referenced data:

```
class Post {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }

    public PostType Type { get; set; { // enum

    public IdeaData IdeaData { get; set; } // != null when Type == PostType.Idea
    public ArticleRequestData ArticleRequestData { get; set; } // != null when Type == PostType.ArticleRequest
    public QuestionData QuestionData { get; set; } // != null when Type == PostType.Question
}
```

In that case I could create one Response class, one Notification class, and one Comment class.

Or maybe there is some other option? If something is unclear, please let me know and I will explain it in more details.

Comment: It seems that you are basically describing almost [Table per Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/inheritance?view=aspnetcore-3.1)(without common base table) and [Table per Hierarchy](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy)

Comment: Yes, that's probably that. Thanks, I didn't know about this.